# Sitecore - Standard values are not displaying

Tags: sitecore

i am creating an item in the sitecore[Item A] programmatically.I would like to assign one more template in the standard values of [Item A]._Standard values item is not getting displayed under ItemA.Is there any option to set the visible settings for __Standard values?

[image]

```
myItem.Template.CreateStandardValues(); //This is how am creating
```

Comment: Am not really sure what you're asking here?  Are you creating a content item programatically, or trying to create templates (with corresponding standard values) programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean _"assign one more template in the standard values of [Item A]"_? What are you trying to assign, a base template?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your item from the tree ('`test'`) in your code is stored in variable `myItem`, your code for creating `Standard Values` for this item template is absolutely fine.

Still you need to remember that `Standard Values` are created for `Template items` **only** so if you want to see the `Standard Values` you've created, you need find the `Template item` for the `test` (just click on this item and follow the `Template` link in the `Quick Info` section) item and there should be a child item of the `Template` called `__Standard Values`.